# How can I use TSQL to check when a user's password will expire?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, credentials

With SQL Server 2005 and above, how can I check when a user's password is going to expire using TSQL?

Preferably this would be done using a connection for that same user. What permissions would be required for the SQL statement to be run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('sa', 'DaysUntilExpiration').

For more accurate data - and also in SQL Server 2005, where DaysUntilExpiration is not supported, a combination of SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('sa', 'PasswordLastSetTime') and the password expiry policy out of Group Policy would do it.

[According to SQL Server help,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412%28SQL.90%29.aspx) this function 'Requires VIEW permission on the login'.